# how to fetch values from file and assign to variable and run in loop

Tags: file, tcl, file-handling

I want to fetch values from text file and assign to variables in loop how to achieve it .
`data.text` file contains two columns

```
Name, Age
ABC  ,  31
def    ,  41
ghi     ,  51
```

I want to pick name from this and assign to `$name` 
then take next value age and assign to `$age`. I will be fetching these by sequence till end of file.

I tried using `foreach` & line but able to fetch complete line maybe this is possible by using regex or list but not sure how to use it

please help with sample program

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a CSV file. You want to use a [proper CSV parser](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) for that.

```
package require csv

set f [open "data.text"]

# Skip the header line; we could parse it, but we won't
gets $f

# Parse the remaining lines
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    lassign [csv::split $line] name age
    # Your data has extra spaces in it, it seems; we deal with that here
    set name [string trim $name]
    set age [string trim $age]
    # Now we'll do something with that
    puts "name is '$name', age is '$age'"
}
close $f
```

---

With Tcl 8.6, you can integrate the trimming more directly:

```
    lassign [lmap value [csv::split $line] {string trim $value}] name age
```

But that's purely a refinement. (8.5 and before don't have `lmap`; you *could* write it with `foreach` and so on, but there's no real point; you can write the code directly enough without it when there's just two fields.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunately my software doesnt have csv package bundled. due to which i cant use above code. Is there any other way to solve this. I used below code but  could not able to place  Name and Age individually. My code reads whole line and place it in name & Age text box                                                                              set Name [open data.txt r]
set file_data [read $Name]
foreach line $file_data {
set -widget m_Name -value $line  #Entering Name in Text box
set -widget m_Age -value  $line

}

Comment: Hello Sir, I found answer for my question. Refer below. But still whole credit goes to you. Thanks for your help.                                                                                                        set file_open [open data.txt r]
 foreach line [split [string trim [read $chan]] \n] {
   lassign $line Name Name 
   puts "a=$Name b=$Name"
 }
 close $file_open